# Epub format ebook and page flipping?

Tags: iphone, epub

I am making  an application which can read ebooks in epub format..I have displayed all the chapters in Webview.   What i want ,that these chapters should shown like a real book.Page by page..so that we can flip the page...but in the web view we have to scroll to read the whole chapter..
i want to make application similar to stanza / ibooks..
any other alternative to show the chapter page by page..or to apply the same effect in webview...??

Comment: if you have whole text of chapter then show it on scroll view with the help of pdf presentation then use page segment property for flip over

Comment: i have the xml/html  file of full chapter...and how to show pdf segment by segment..?

Comment: epub essentially is format which has no pre-cooked pages. your rendering engine makes decision on pagination, depending on screen properties and piece of text to be rendered. in other words, epub is _no_ PDF or PostScript where you have pagination put into document. Because of this, you can read epub on any screen (or print on any printer) which has sensible size of page, while in PDF you have to reformat page for any new destination page size.